# Multiple Flat File Outputs to a folder in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2017

I am using SSIS2017 and part of what I am doing involves running several (30ish) SQL scripts to be output into flat files into the same folder. My question is, to do this do I have to create 30 New File Connections or is there a way to define the folder I want all the outputs to go to, and have them saved there?

I am only really thinking of keeping a tidy Connection Manager tab. If there's a more efficient way to do it than 30something file connections that would be great?

Comment: I might take it a step further and only have one data flow per package. So in this case, 30 packages all from SQL source to a flat file.

Comment: Thanks @KeithL I think thats what I will end up doing. It was more just to try to maintain a simpler environment without 30+ connections in the connection manager

Answer (score 1):

A data flow is tightly bound to the columns and types defined within for performance reasons.

If your use case is "I need to generate an extract of sales by year for the past 30ish" then yes, you can make do with a single Flat File Connection Manager because the columns and data types will not change - you're simply segmenting the data.

However, if your use case is "I need to extract Sales, Employees, Addresses, etc" then you will need a Flat File Connection Manager (and preferably a data flow) per entity/data shape.

It's my experience that you would be nicely served by designing this as 30ish packages (SQL Source -> Flat File Destination) with an overall orchestrator package that uses Execute Package Task to run the dependent processes. Top benefits

- You can have a team of developers work on the individual packages
- Packages can be re-run individually in the event of failure
- Better performance

Being [me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A181965%20biml), I'd also look at [Biml](https://bimlscript.com) and see whether you can't just script all that out.

### Addressing comments

To future proof location info, I'd define a project parameter of something like `BaseFilePath` (assuming the most probably change is that dev I use a path of something like C:\ssisdata\input\file1.txt, C:\ssisdata\input\file3.csv and then production would be \server\share\input\file1.txt or E:\someplace\for\data\file1.txt) which I would populate with the dev value `C:\ssisdata\input` and then assign the value of `\\server\share\input` for the production to the project via configuration.

The crucial piece would be to ensure that an Expression exists on the Flat File Connection Manager's `ConnectionString` property to driven, in part, by the parameter's value. Again, being a programmatically lazy person, I have a Variable named `CurrentFilePath` with an expression like `@[Project$::BaseFilePath] + "\\file1.csv"`

The FFCM then uses @[User::CurrentFilePath] to ensure I write the file to the correct location. And since I create 1 package per extract, I don't have to worry about creating a Variable per flat file connection manager as it's all the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Each of the SQL statements will have its own data flow (input and output stored in there) so thats fine, it was just trying to future proof a way that maybe if the location the files have to go to changes, I dont have to go through 30+ connections to amend them.

Comment: @MikeLanglois Added some thoughts on future proofing